# What is the use of federated user repository VMM

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have read about the federated user repository VMM from [WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Expand your user registry options with a federated repository](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0701_ilechko/0701_ilechko.html)

I'd like to know the following things:

- What are the uses of federated user repository and VMM?
- Can we use these repository directly in the application which is deployed in that server? If yes then how to refer to this repository in application?
- The document also says about the limitations as well, so are these limitations also present in WAS 7.0 ND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the uses of federated user repository and VMM?

Federated repository  IS your user repository. Users from the repository can be assigned to

- administrative roles - to manage WebSphere Application Server via admin console and/or wsadmin scripting tool
- application roles - to define which users/groups have rights to access certain web resources or execute EJB methods

> Can we use these repository directly in the application which is
>   deployed in that server? If yes then how to refer this repository in
>   application?

For basic functionality you can use Java EE API, such as `request.getUserPrincipal(), request.isUserInRole(role)`.
For more advanced usage check the flowing pages:

- [Virtual member manager documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/welcome.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-3-31&lang=en)
- [Developing with Virtual member manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/developing.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-3-31-5&lang=en)
- [Programming model and API refernce](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/references.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-3-31-8&lang=en)

> The document also says about the limitations as well, so did this limitation also present in WAS 7.0 ND?

Some limitations are lifted in v7, other are lifted in v8, some still exist:

- *Only one user repository can be configured to be the target for creating users/groups from the administration console.* - still **exists**
- *The username (for example, LDAP uid) must be unique across the different repositories.* - still **exist**, however you can define [multiple security domains](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/csec_sec_multiple_domains.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F1-8-30-1-0&lang=en) with different repositories for different servers, and in V8.x you may have many federated repository confiugrations.
- *If one or more repository in the federation is down, you will not be able to authenticate* - **lifted** - you need to configure it via wsadmin in v7.0 or via console in v8.x
- *Although VMM has the capability to support multiple realms, WebSphere Application Server only supports a single realm at this time.* - **addressed** by [multiple security domains](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/csec_sec_multiple_domains.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F1-8-30-1-0&lang=en)

Comment: Is there any dependency of servers with deployment manager w.r.t VMM authentication? We have WAS 7.0 ND, so if deployment manager machine is down and one of the server (serverA) is up, is there any problem in the application which uses VMM for authentication and is deployed in that server (serverA)?

Comment: @paramupk no, the security service runs in each JVM, so deployment manager may be down, and authentication will still correctly be handled on any server in the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. When you say cell, this means nodeagent process should be also started on only the server process is enough.

Comment: @paramupk Nodeagent in general should be running as it allows management of your server from deployment manager. However, if you are asking whether app server will run correctly, if node agent is temporary down, then the answer is yes. Nodeagent is not SPOF.

Comment: As said by you WAS 7.0 supports Multiple realm, i wanted to confirm one more thing. We have LDAP and external authorization service called IAM (Opensso). As per opensso doc we need to use Standalone custom registry [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7250/gicqi/index.html) (Step 3 --> c) and our application need to be authenticated using ldap or IAM. So wanted to check if we can have both federated repository & Standalone custom registry active or set as current. And can we integrate VMM with Standalone custom registry (any reference will also help).

Comment: @paramupk No, it is not possible to combine Standalone CUR and VMM Ldap. However you could write VMM custom adapter (which is VMM equivalent of CUR) and then have federated of that adapter and LDAP. Check the link for adapter http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwim_dev_vmmca.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. IAM works based on URL redirection, when you login to application or console which is integrated with IAM, it redirects url, login page of IAM server appears, after succesfull login cookie is set and user is autheticated. I am just wondering how to right an adaptor for this..

Comment: @paramupk In that case you may also consider using TAI, which can do the redirection and then validate returned token. But it is too broad discussion for chat like this, as you should also consider whether user registries for IAM and WAS are the same (I'm talking about user population like same LDAP).

Comment: the problem is user registries in IAM and LDAP are different.